# How to replace directly NaN values in a column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
article_id          title
NaN                 title_1
NaN                 title_2
NaN                 title_3
'202102011404103'   title_4
'202102011404104'   title_5
NaN                 title_6
```

Firstly I would like to add a condition 'if there is NaN value do the following' (else do nothing).
**If** there is NaN value in the column:
I would like to add directly an incremental value to NaN values in the column with something like this:

```
x = 1
df.insert(0, 'article_id', range(x, x + len(df)))
```

But I don't know how to add directly the code above to the column article_id, only to NaN values.
How can I do it ?

Expected output:

```
article_id              title
    1                   title_1
    2                   title_2
    3                   title_3
    '202102011404103'   title_4
    '202102011404104'   title_5
    4                   title_6
```

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Comment: Hello, I updated my post

Answer (score 2):

You can create mask for compare missing values and pass range with first value with count of `NaN`s by `sum`:

```
m = df['article_id'].isna()

x = 1
df.loc[m, 'article_id'] =  range(x, x + m.sum())
print (df)
          article_id    title
0                  1  title_1
1                  2  title_2
2                  3  title_3
3  '202102011404103'  title_4
4  '202102011404104'  title_5
5                  4  title_6
```